# Updating mongoDB document takes two times

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this Schema:

```
const opening_hourSchema = new Schema({
    sunday:         {open: { type: Boolean, default: true}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    monday:         {open: { type: Boolean, default: true}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    tuesday:        {open: { type: Boolean, default: true}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    wednesday:      {open: { type: Boolean, default: true}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    thursday:       {open: { type: Boolean, default: true}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    friday:         {open: { type: Boolean, default: false}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
    saturday:       {open: { type: Boolean, default: false}, from: { type: String, default: "10:00"}, to: { type: String, default: "19:00"} },
}
, { timestamps: true });
```

I want to update it with an object that looks like this:

```
opening_hours:
friday: {open: false, from: "06:20", to: "13:00"}
monday: {open: false, from: "02:00", to: "09:00"}
saturday: {open: false, from: "07:00", to: "14:00"}
sunday: {open: false, from: "01:00", to: "08:00"}
thursday: {open: false, from: "05:00", to: "12:00"}
tuesday: {open: false, from: "03:00", to: "10:00"}
wednesday: {open: false, from: "04:00", to: "11:00"}
__proto__: Object
_id: "5fbd18517954d20024a132b4"
```

This is my function to accomplish the update.

```
router.post('/set-open-hours', auth, function (req, res) {
  OpeningHours.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id , req.body.opening_hours)
  .then((opening_hours) => {
    res.json(opening_hours)
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error2: " + err));
})
```

The strange this is that it works, but takes two tries for some reason. If I call the function once it will return the old object. The second time around it will return the correct object, for some reason.

Comment: after calling this function once , can you please check the result in database. tell me that what it shows.

Comment: because I want to make sure that whether data is updated or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the findByIdAndUpdate() method returns that matched the condition before the update operation.

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, {new: true})
```

{new: true} this will return the updated result.